# Copy(Texto,1,até espaço em branco)

Tags: delphi

Tenho um texto (456/2017 1.1 Conheça os Paises) e as vezes tenho (45/17 1.1 .....)
como faço para pegar com o comando copy(Texto,1,espaço em branco)?

Comment: Copy(Texto,1,Pos('  ',Texto)-1);

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a função `POS` para retornar a posição do primeiro caractere `espaço`:

```
Copy(Texto, 1, POS(' ', Texto) - 1);
```